# JAXB EclipseLink Moxy add template xml

Tags: java, templates, jaxb, eclipselink

i have problem with my jaxb EclipseLink implementation.

Let's assume I have the following Entity ...

```
@XmlRootElement(name = GenericConfigEntity.XML_ROOT_TAG)
public class GenericConfigEntity {

    private String name;
    private String data;
    private String version;
    private String date;
    private String template;

    @XmlAttribute(name = GenericConfigEntity.XML_NAME)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = GenericConfigEntity.XML_DATA)
    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name = GenericConfigEntity.XML_VERSION)
    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name = GenericConfigEntity.XML_DATE)
    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public String getTemplate() {
        return template;
    }

    public void setTemplate(String template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

}
```

The string 'template' contains xml data already let's say someting like this (in my real context it is a lot more and I do not want to create the entities for this).

```
<Prozess name="xx" test="1">
    <Debug system="test" />
</Prozess>
```

Now my question is if there is a way to integrate the template string into the marshalling process that someting like this is generated

```
<conf name="xx" version="x" datum="xx"> 
    <Prozess name="xx" test="1">
        <Debug system="test" />
    </Prozess>
    <Data>
        TextTextText
    </Data>
</conf>
```

It is no solution to wrap the template in an  tag because i am restricted to this layout.

Also @XmlValue is no solution because I get an exception "all other elements have to be an attribute because one is marked as xmlvalue".

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this myself yet, but I reckon you could use the `@XmlAnyElement` in conjunction with a `DomHandler` to implement such a mapping. You can find a helpful example in the blog of MOXy's lead programmer [here](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/xmlanyelement-and-non-dom-properties.html).

I think you'd still have to make sure that the XML content in your template field has at least an opening and a closing tag, which serve to identify the DOM element during (un)marshalling. That tag may be arbitrary as required by you. I guess you could just look for the first tag appearing in the string and try to match it against the end of the string.